# R transfer column to another column of a new data frame that is empty

Tags: r, dataframe, transfer

I tried to create a new dataframe that is called `newDataFrame`, with the columns: `one`, `two` and `three`. You can see the datatypes below. What i want now is to transfer the data from `oldDataFrame` with an `ifelse` statement to the new dataframe. So what i want is to copy the column from the old dataframe to the column `one` in the new dataFrame.

```
 # create new dataframe with the right types
 newDataFrame <- data.frame(one= numeric(0), two= integer(0), three= character(0))
 str(newDataFrame )
 as.data.frame(newDataFrame )
 # try to store the column x of the old frame to the new dataframe by conditions
 newDataFrame$one<- ifelse(substr(oldDataframe_v7$x, start=1, stop=1)=="A", TRUE, FALSE)
```

What i get is an error:

`$<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "one", value = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,))` 
     `Replacement has 261217 rows, data have 0`

How can i transfer data from one data frame by ifelse to another one that is not filled yet?

Comment: `Replacement has 261217 rows, data have 0`

Comment: your problem is not reproducible since we don't know what's in `oldDataframe_v7$x`

Comment: A data frame is a list where each element has the same length. You can not just assign to one variable a vector of some length, which is what you are trying to do, because then one would have length 3 and the rest length 0. I think it would help to say what you are trying to achieve with this, and why you need a new data frame.

Comment: well what i want is to create a new dataframe where extracted data from the old one is stored. so i can make tests on the new frame not using the old one. i just want a copy of specific columns of the old data frame in  a new one. the column of the old dataframe just got data with TRUE and FALSE entries and i have some conditions that has to be tested whether the entries will be stored or not.

Comment: Selecting columns can be done with `dplyr::select`. `newDataFrame <- dplyr::select(oldDataFrame, x)` for example.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that solved my problem!! very nice! so happy that it works!

Answer (score 0):

First Data Frame

```
data = data.frame(x=c(1,5,7,10),y=c(3,2,4,1.1),z=1:4)
data 
#    x    y  z
# 1  1  3.0  1
# 2  5  2.0  2
# 3  7  4.0  3
# 4 10  1.1  4

data1=data.frame(one=numeric(nrow(data)),two=integer(nrow(data)),three=character(nrow(data)))
data1 
#   one two three
# 1   0   0      
# 2   0   0      
# 3   0   0      
# 4   0   0     

data1$one<-data$x
data1
#   one two three
# 1   1   0      
# 2   5   0      
# 3   7   0      
# 4  10   0
```

The code above is without conditions.Hope this might have helped a little.